# Passing Incorrect Value to Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, php, pass-by-reference, truncation

I am attempting to pass a string '0541210022-0' to a popup window through a Javascript method. When I view the number in my popup window it shows up as 11575826. Can someone please help me determine why this value is changing? I will add code as well as screen shots. Thank you!

Code for popup window. First HTML/PHP Button then javascript.

HTML/PHP

```
<?php
    $Number = $row['N1']."-".$row['N2'];
?>
 <button onClick="openPopup(<?php echo $idt;?>, <?php echo $Number;?>);"><?php echo $idt;?></button>
```

Javascript

```
function openPopup(id, Number) {
    alert(Number);
    document.getElementById('draggable').style.display = 'block';
    if ( true ) console.log( "This element is draggable!" );
    if ( false ) console.log( "This element failed at being draggable!" );
    document.getElementById('popupID').innerHTML = id;
    document.getElementById('popupNumber').innerHTML = Number;
}
```

At this point number is = 11575826. Next I will show you the screen shots to help visualize what I am seeing.

Number being outputted to a table cell. As you can see it is 054121022-0.

[image]

Next I will show the number being showing in the java alert, which should be the same number but it changes somehow. As you can see the number is very different from what it should be.

[image]

Thank you for the help! I am very confused as to why this is happening. I fear that somehow the value is being truncated, but I do not know how to pass the value to the Javascript function as a string.

Comment: Since it is used by js as a function you shouldn't use `Number` as a variable in your js. What exactly do you think `if ( true )` and `if(false)` will do? `true` is always true and `false` is always false, so the first `if` will always run and the second won't ever run. You need to sit down add a few `console.log("msg")` statements and trace out what your code is doing. If you don't have a clear statement of what you intend to do to compare to, do that first.

Comment: Are those fake variable names given just for the example? You should avoid naming a variable "Number", given that it's a function. Also, what are those true / false inexistent comparissons for? I see now I'm just repeating things already said. You should post some of the table's html for further reference, something that can show us what the `#draggable` element is and where are you allegedly taking the number from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should add the quotes in this way:

```
<button onClick="openPopup(<?php echo $idt; ?>, '<?php echo $Number; ?>');"><?php echo $idt; ?></button>
```

Answer (score 4):

11575826 (decimal) is the same as 054121002 (octal), and Javascript (like most C-ish languages) treats numbers with leading zeros as octal. Not sure why the last 2 is being truncated, or if that's a typo, but you're calling

```
openPopup(WhateverIdtIs, 054121002-0);
```

which is the same as

```
openPopup(WhateverIdtIs, 11575826-0);
```

You need to quote the string for it to remain a string:

```
<button onClick="openPopup('<?php echo $idt;?>', '<?php echo $Number;?>');"><?php echo $idt;?></button>
```